# Changing SQL CONSTRAINT Based On Other Fields

Tags: sql, mysql, t-sql

I have an SQL table written in MSSQL:

```
create table [action]
(
    action_id       bigint identity not null,   -- PK
    action_action   char(1) not null,       -- 'C' Call, 'R' Raise, 'F' Fold, 'P' Post
    action_size     decimal(9,2) not null,  -- zero if fold, > zero otherwise

    constraint pk_action primary key clustered (action_id),
    constraint chk_action_action check (action_action in('C','R','F','P'))
)
```

I want to put a constraint on the `action_size` column such that:

1) If `action_action` is 'F' then `action_size` must be 0.00 (or null if that is more doable)
2) If `action_action` is anything other than 'F' then `action_size` must be greater than zero (ie >= 0.01)

How do I express this?  I tried:

```
constraint chk_action_size check (
    select action_action
        case 'F'    action_size = 0.00
        else        action_size > 0.00
)
```

...to no avail.

I'm writing this in MSSQL 2005 but would like a solution that works with MySQL 5.1.34 also.

BTW if you would care to comment on my `action_action` column, feel free.  There will either never be other valid values for `action_action` or, if there are, it will be exceedingly rare and there will only be ~1 other valid value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table [action]
(
    action_id           bigint identity not null,
    action_action       char(1) not null, 
    action_size         decimal(9,2) not null,

    constraint pk_action primary key clustered (action_id),
    constraint chk_action_action check (action_action in('C','R','F','P')),
    constraint chk_action_size check 
    (
         (action_action = 'F' AND action_size = 0.00) OR
         (action_action <> 'F' AND action_size > 0.00)
     )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE action ADD CONSTRAINT chk_action_size CHECK (
    (action_action = 'F' AND action_size = 0.00)
    OR (action_action <> 'F' AND action_size > 0.00)
)
```

If you were using floats instead of decimals, write the zero check as:

```
ABS(action_size) > 0.01
```

Since floats may not be exactly zero, especially after some math.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a trigger?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html